# How to receive data on web server with PHP?

Tags: php, hosting

I have a server at a host, so I can't control the server directly and therefore don't have ability to start Windows cmd or a Linux shell. I want a PHP script on the server to receive data from a incoming connection (client: created with a Python script).

I know about database and so on, but can't find a PHP example, where it's done on a host server with limited control. It seems that all guides are for HTML pages or for use where you have the server in own hands.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get what your question is, please rewrite it more clearly.

Comment: Would you describe the nature of the "incoming connection" a bit more? What port is this using? If it is just a post to port 80 then any PHP host can do that. Just examine the contents of `$_POST` and store them in your database.

Comment: So if i send this with a Python script using urllib2:

Host Update:" https://www.someserver.com/visitor.php? u=someone@youmail.dk&p=password&function=26&opcode0=0
" All it takes in visitor.php is to have a varable i.e Incoming = $_POST
???
I thought it's was only used with .html-pages.
I'll give it a try. :-D

Comment: Yes, use `$_POST` or `$_GET`, depending on the HTTP method actually in use. If it is writing data, post sounds more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to receive form data from client then you can use POST or GET method to receive data from client to server.

Comment: I try those syntaxs and se what happends.